# How fire up input textbox keypress event using with jquery without typing

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

I want to fire up input textbox `keypress` event using with jquery without typing.
Take a look at this snippet :

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Is that what a want?
But those codes has error :

> Cannot read property 'which' of undefiend

How can i bypass that error and fire up input textbox `keypress` event using with jquery without typing?

---

Also i tried this :

```
$('#input').val('string');
$('#input').keypress();
```

Same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `$.ui.keyCode` to work you need to include `jquery-ui.js`

**Without `jquery-ui`**

```js
$(function(){
  var e = $.Event("keypress");
  e.which = 13;
  $('input').trigger(e);
});

$('input').on('keypress',function(e){
  if(e.which==13)
    alert('Enter pressed automatically');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

**With `jquery-ui`**

```js
$(function(){
  var e = $.Event("keypress");
  e.which = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
  $('input').trigger(e);
});

$('input').on('keypress',function(e){
  if(e.which==13)
    alert('Enter pressed automatically');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" />
```

Comment: But i still have that error! Should i import jquery ui like this? https://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/

Comment: No.. You can do it like this - `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Use this solution with jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $.Event("keypress", {which: 13});
    $('input').trigger(e);
});
$('input').on('keypress',function(e){
    console.log(e.which+' -- KeyPress event Fired');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```